# NestJS dependency injection of service fails inside MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync call

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I need to have a pre-save hook on my User model. Here is my `users.module.ts`:

```js
@Module({
  controllers: [
    UsersController,
  ],
  exports: [
    UsersService,
  ],
  providers: [
    UsersService,
  ],
  imports: [
    forwardRef(() => AuthModule),
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: User.name,
        useFactory: (usersService: UsersService) => {
          const schema = UserSchema;

          schema.pre('save', async function(next) {
            // ... more code

            next();
          });

          return schema;
        },
        inject: [UsersService],
      }
    ]),
  ]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

However, I receive an error stating:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserModel (DatabaseConnection,
> ?). Please make sure that the argument UsersService at index [1] is
> available in the MongooseModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - Is MongooseModule a valid NestJS module?
> - If UsersService is a provider, is it part of the current MongooseModule?
> - If UsersService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MongooseModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing UsersService */ ]   })
>
> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserModel
> (DatabaseConnection, ?). Please make sure that the argument
> UsersService at index [1] is available in the MongooseModule context.

The users service, minus methods and imports is:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User.name)
    private readonly userModel: Model<User>,
  ) {}

}
```

If I remove `forFeatureAsync` and replace it with `forFeature`, everything works as expected.

If I remove `inject: [UsersService]` and remove the parameter from useFactory, it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to make a circular dependency between the `UserService` and the `UserModel`. That won't ever work. Depending on what you're trying to do pre-save, you might be able to abstract the functionality out to a separate module and service and use *that* in the `forFeatureAsync`, just don't forget to import the new module if so

Comment: Thanks Jay. I think I might be able to work around this. I appreciate the explanation!